# is there an easy way to archive historical pinescript code

Tags: pine-script

when I go to "My scripts" in the editor, I see all the versions of all my scripts.  It would be great if you could create a folder structure so I could archive older versions, or scripts I'm not currently using.  Any way to do this without having to copy and paste the script to a text file for storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Tradingview does not support folder structures at the moment. One thing they support is script version history. However, you need to remember which script version has which changes.

[image]